# Different close buttons on tabs

Tags: qt4, qtabbar

I am using QTabWidget, and I would like to know if I can use different icons for close buttons on tabs? I think style and setCornerWidget may not work for this case.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think that this is possible with a QTabWidget. You could use a QTabBar where you can use QTabBar::setTabButton to set a widget of your own design into the tab position.

Answer (score 6):

Use [setStyleSheet](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qwidget.html#styleSheet-prop)() with

```
 QTabBar::close-button {
     image: url(close.png)
 }
 QTabBar::close-button:hover {
     image: url(close-hover.png)
 }
```

http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/stylesheet-examples.html#customizing-qtabwidget-and-qtabbar

Answer (score 1):

```cpp
#include <QProxyStyle>

class AppStyle : public QProxyStyle
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    AppStyle(QStyle *style = 0) : QProxyStyle(style) {}
    
    void drawPrimitive(QStyle::PrimitiveElement element, const QStyleOption *option, QPainter *painter, const QWidget *widget) const
    {
        if (element == PE_IndicatorTabClose)
        {
            int size = proxy()->pixelMetric(QStyle::PM_SmallIconSize);
            QIcon::Mode mode = option->state & State_Enabled ?
            (option->state & State_Raised ? QIcon::Active : QIcon::Normal)
            : QIcon::Disabled;
            if (!(option->state & State_Raised)
                && !(option->state & State_Sunken)
                && !(option->state & QStyle::State_Selected))
                mode = QIcon::Disabled;
            
            QIcon::State state = option->state & State_Sunken ? QIcon::On : QIcon::Off;
            QPixmap pixmap = QIcon(":myclose.png").pixmap(size, mode, state);
            proxy()->drawItemPixmap(painter, option->rect, Qt::AlignCenter, pixmap);
        }
        else
        {
            QProxyStyle::drawPrimitive(element,option,painter,widget);
        }
    }
};
```

in main.cpp:

```cpp
QApplication app(argc, argv);
app.setStyle(new AppStyle(app.style()));
```

Answer (score 0):

The default close buttons on tabs are part of the `QStyle` you are using.

From the Qt sources:

```
    case PE_IndicatorTabClose: {
        if (d->tabBarcloseButtonIcon.isNull()) {
            d->tabBarcloseButtonIcon.addPixmap(QPixmap(
                        QLatin1String(":/trolltech/styles/commonstyle/images/standardbutton-closetab-16.png")),
                        QIcon::Normal, QIcon::Off);
            d->tabBarcloseButtonIcon.addPixmap(QPixmap(
                        QLatin1String(":/trolltech/styles/commonstyle/images/standardbutton-closetab-down-16.png")),
                        QIcon::Normal, QIcon::On);
            d->tabBarcloseButtonIcon.addPixmap(QPixmap(
                        QLatin1String(":/trolltech/styles/commonstyle/images/standardbutton-closetab-hover-16.png")),
                        QIcon::Active, QIcon::Off);
        }
```

From what it looks, you have to subclass QStyle and override `PE_IndicatorTabClose` and return a different QIcon path.

Comment: Great. But l think I may have to pass in a value for tab ID.

Answer (score 0):

For instance, if you want to change the icon to one with transparent background, and change the background icon on hovering:

```css
QTabBar::close-button
{
    image: url(:icons/close.svg)
}

QTabBar::close-button:hover
{
    background: #A0A0A0
}
```